# Cardinality of $\{\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(\emptyset), \{\emptyset\} \} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is an old exam question from "Diskrete Mathematik" at ETH Zurich

$\mathcal{P}(A)$ denotes the Powerset, which is the set of all subsets of A:

$\mathcal{P}(A) := \{S|S\subseteq A \}$.

I believe that  $\{\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(\emptyset), \{\emptyset\} \} $ since
$\mathcal{P}(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\} $ can be reduced to $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} \} $ and thus the cardinality of said set would be 2. However, the inofficial solution is 3.

Comment: Who wrote this unofficial solution? Unofficial solutions have the problem that they might contain typos. I mean, also official solutions can contain typos, but that's another story.

Comment: Can you be absolutely, totally, 100% sure that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$?

Comment: @Daniel: Good point, in some old set theory texts, it sometimes appeared as $S(X)$ actually. (I guess "subsets"...)

Comment: Your answer, $2$, is correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes

Answer (score 1):

The power set of a finite set with cardinality $x$ has cardinality $2^x$. As you pointed out, $\{\emptyset, \mathcal{P}(\emptyset), \{\emptyset\} \}$ can be simplified down to $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} \}$, which is equivalent to $\mathcal{P}(\{\emptyset\})$. Using the property I described initially, we end up with,

$$
2^{|\{\emptyset\}|} = 2^1 = 2.
$$

Therefore, the correct solution is $2$ and not $3$ as the unofficial solution suggested.